# How can I stop bazel from creating an entire copy of my project's source files?

Tags: bazel

I have a simple Java project in a directory called `java-fun`. Bazel is installed and runs correctly. But whenever it runs, it generates a directory called `bazel-java-fun` that contains copies of all the `src/.../*.java` files from my root directory `java-fun`.

Now my IDE displays a conflicting class name error: `Duplicate class found in the file '/Users/traviscramer/java-fun/bazel-java-fun/src/main/Main.java'` for every single Java class.

Is there a way to configure bazel so that it doesn't create this `bazel-<project name>` directory in my workspace?

Comment: Those should be symlinks, not actual copies. In any case, you can override where Bazel stores these copies, check out `--output_user_root` and `--output_base`. I'd rather configure the IDE to ignore those files though. Sometimes, when just placed in the .gitignore file, that is already picked up by the IDE.

Comment: Thanks. I will likely configure my IDE to ignore them. But why does it need to create these symlinks in the first place?

Comment: Bazel tries to maintain control over the build environment. Symlinking the relevant files guarantees that irrelevant files are not used without noticing that. Having this control is important for cache invalidation purposes and caching is one of _the_ Bazel features.

Comment: Right, for the exec root (where actions are executed) and for runfiles trees (runtime files for binaries) the symlink trees are for showing the action only the inputs it declared for hermeticity. (And symlinks (or junctions on Windows) are used for performance.) The `bazel-*` symlinks that Bazel creates at the root of the workspace are just for the user's convenience though. https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/output_directories.html#layout-diagram

Comment: Just in case the previous link goes dead (it contains a warning already): https://bazel.build/docs/output_directories.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.bazelrc` in your WORKSPACE.

Add to `.bazelrc`:

```
build --symlink_prefix=/ # Out of source build
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what is typically common practice here?